# I'm new to Next.js, and I want to create multiple page folders while using only one dynamic route, [id]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
my-nextjs-app/
|-- .next/
|-- node_modules/
|-- public/
|-- src/
|   |-- components/
|       |-- men/
|       |   |-- [id]/
|       |       |-- page.tsx      # Static page for specific ID within Men's category
|       |   |-- page.tsx          # Static page for Men's category
|       |-- women/
|       |   |-- [id]/
|       |       |-- page.tsx      # Static page for specific ID within Women's category
|       |   |-- page.tsx          # Static page for Women's category
|       |-- teen/
|           |-- [id]/
|               |-- page.tsx      # Static page for specific ID within Teen's category
|           |-- page.tsx          # Static page for Teen's category
|   |-- styles/
|-- .gitignore
|-- package.json
|-- README.md
```

Is it possible to use only one **`[id]`** across all folders in the **`pages`** directory? I want the **`men`**, **`women`**, and **`teen`** folders to share a common `[id].

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by having one id? With your current routes you have three different routes with a dynamic subroute each. Those subroutes can be combined using a common component, but I don't thing that is what you are looking for. Does switching around the route to `[id]/category` help your case?

Comment: can you teach me how to combine this subroutes? using component

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Next.js, you can share a common `[id]` parameter across multiple folders.

This is an example of the files structure:

```
my-nextjs-app/
|-- .next/
|-- node_modules/
|-- public/
|-- src/
|   |-- components/
|       |-- sharedId/
|       |   |-- [id].tsx         # Shared page for specific ID
|       |-- men/
|       |   |-- [id].tsx         # Reference the shared [id] page for Men's category
|       |   |-- index.tsx        # Optional: Men's category main page
|       |-- women/
|       |   |-- [id].tsx         # Reference the shared [id] page for Women's category
|       |   |-- index.tsx        # Optional: Women's category main page
|       |-- teen/
|       |   |-- [id].tsx         # Reference the shared [id] page for Teen's category
|       |   |-- index.tsx        # Optional: Teen's category main page
|   |-- styles/
|-- .gitignore
|-- package.json
|-- README.md
```

In this structure:

The `[id].tsx` file inside the sharedId folder is the common page for handling specific IDs.
Inside the men, women, and teen folders, the `[id].tsx` files are simply references to the shared `[id].tsx` file within the sharedId folder. These files can contain specific content or logic relevant to each category if needed.
Additionally, you can have optional `index.tsx` files within each category folder to serve as main pages for each category if desired.

I hope this helps you solve your question :)